# read a html5 web database from android

Tags: android, sql, html, sqlite

A html5 page is loaded in a webview, the user enters data though this html5 page and its stored in the web sql database. This part is working ok. Now when the device comes online i want to access the stored web sql database from the android side and post the data to a server somewhere.
Before you tell me to just have a native android app and use android's sqlite database, its out of my control and thats the approach that has been decided on.

So is it possible to read a web sql database from the android side? If the answer is yes, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to know the sqlite bd's location:

```
 try
     {
         String appname= this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
         String bdlocation="/data/data/"+appname+"/app_database/file__0/0000000000000001.db";

 }
     catch (IOException e)
 {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

and use bdlocation in java to open database.

Regards